# Как установить свою тему оформления в Kodachi Linux

Tags: linux, xfce, kodachi-linux

Как в Kodachi Linux установить свою тему оформления? Не могу найти где и как это сделать

Comment: https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes - так же как везде где используется xfce в качестве окружения рабочего стола

Comment: @L.F.C. следует задать автору вопрос, причём тут метка `gnome`. Kodachi основан на Xubuntu и использует Xfce. Если базовая DE была изменена, то это нужно было упомянуть в вопросе.

Comment: @L.F.C. , потому что в данном дистрибутиве используется xfce, а не gnome

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Я то знаю что он на Xfce, я ж эту метку и создавал. В таком варианте тогда надо закрывать вопрос, если автор не реагирует